# Pandas .dt.hour formatting

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `datetime64[ns]` format object in a pandas dataframe.

I can use this column to compute the hour via:

```
df['hour'] = df['datetime'].dt.hour
```

This returns an integer. e.g :

```
datetime                        hour
19-10-2015 2015-10-19 01:00:00  1
```

What is the easiest way to output the `hour` column in the `01:00:00` time format?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you need [`dt.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html):

```
df['hour'] = df['datetime'].dt.time
print (df)
             datetime      hour
0 2015-10-19 01:00:00  01:00:00
```

But if need truncate datetimes to hours:

```
df['hour'] = df['datetime'].values.astype('<M8[h]')
df['hour'] = df['hour'].dt.time
print (df)
             datetime      hour
0 2015-10-19 01:00:00  01:00:00
1 2015-10-19 01:50:00  01:00:00
```

A bit hack - [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and add string `:00:00`:

```
df['hour'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%H').add(':00:00')
print (df)
             datetime      hour
0 2015-10-19 01:00:00  01:00:00
1 2015-10-19 01:50:00  01:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

@jezrael has it covered... This answer will look just like `.dt.time` but be a string instead

```
df.assign(hour=df.datetime.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))

             datetime      hour
0 2015-10-19 01:00:00  01:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert it to object and then use str.split(' ') to divide the row into date section and time section, then you can assign each part to a column or replace the current one.

```
df['date'], df['hour'] = df['datetime'].str.split(' ', 1).str
print (df)
         datetime       date         hour
0 2015-10-19 01:00:00   2015-10-19   01:00:00
1 2015-10-19 01:50:00   2015-10-19   01:50:00
```